# providing a list with a select query

Tags: mysql

So I have a table named Medics with name, surname, speciality. The total number of specialities are 17 and 108 doctors.

> Speciality: reumatologie, o.r.l, chirurgie, neurolog etc

I need to provide a query to give me the list in this format:

> reumatologie - 5, o.r.l - 4, chirugie - 10

Where 5, 4, and 10 are the number of medics from the table. It's more like saying in speciality reumatologie we have 5 medics that correspond to that kind of speciality.

I've tried this concantenating, and more other selects and none of them worked properly. I'm thinking maybe it will work with a case? If yes, how?

The final select query that works is:

> select Speciality, Count(distinct m_id) as NRofMedics
>   from Medics 
>   group by Speciality;

Comment: It will work with a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`

Comment: @lanzz, I said i've tried that in multiple selects, how exactly do you use them to provide the list exactly like the one I mentioned above? For example this but it gives an error: select CONCAT(Speciality, '-', COUNT(DISTINCT m_id)) GROUP BY Speciality;

Comment: group_concat ? (this is a fuzzy question, you can however, do a GROUP and loop thru all the rows)

Comment: Nobody can help you debug a "this gives an error" problem before you actually tell what the error is. "Does not work" means nothing.

Comment: I only wrote that command to show you an example of how I tried to make that select work.

Comment: Indeed that's a great start, I'll start trying with group concat maybe I'll figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lanzz is right. However, try something like below-

```
select Speciality, Count(distinct name) 
from Medics 
group by Speciality
```

hope this helps.

Comment: In this command it's counted the specialities. However I need to count the number of medics that correspond to a certain speciality. More like neurologist - 10 doctors and so on

Comment: I guess you can do the rest following the idea.

Comment: As I said i'm trying to see if it works, even though if I want to get the result set in this format: speciality- numberofdoctors with that kind of speciality. isn't needed maybe a CONCAT after all ?

Comment: So finally I think I've got it, thanks a lot @V.P. Verma I modified it a bit and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Speciality || '-' || count(distinct name) as 'Med with Speciality' 
from Medics group by speciality
```

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough. in the result set I should get: Speciality1 - NrofDoctorsWithThisSpeciality, below Speciality2 - NrOfDoctorsWithThisSpeciality. With your command I get a result set with a straight count of 1, 1, 1, 1,1

Comment: @SAdrian, which column does specify doctor ... I thought you are looking for speciality with medicine.

Comment: It's more like @V.P Verma's command. Instead of speciality counted I needed the doctors counted from each speciality and I updated it and works. Thanks you as well for the reply on such a short notice I wish I could upvote both of your answers.